# Generating fibonacci number is C

Tags: c, arrays, fibonacci

I was practicing array in C. I have found a code mentioned bellow.

```
int main(void)
{
    int  numbers[10] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int  i, j;

    **for (j = 0;  j < 10;  ++j)
        for (i = 0;  i < j;  ++i)
            numbers[j]  = numbers[j] +numbers[i];**

    for (j = 0;  j < 10;  ++j)
        printf("%i ", numbers[j]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I know that it's a silly question. If anyone help me to understand the Bold marked for loop, I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tihis is not a Fibonacci sequence, you're just doubling the value to the next array position.

Comment: Wherever you "found" this code, if they claimed a Fibonacci sequence as the result, they're lying.

Comment: I have found this code on an exercise session of a book called Programming in C by Stephen G. Kochan. This exercise was just about making an assumption of the output.   In the following link https://github.com/cdude996/Programming-in-C/blob/master/chapter06/ex5.c  that series has been claimed as fibonacci.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (j = 0;  j < 10;  ++j)
    for (i = 0;  i < j;  ++i)
        numbers[j]  = numbers[j] +numbers[i];
```

The above loop will target particular position of the array and will add all the numbers one by one from 0th position to selected position.

**Eventually you are not generating the Fibonacci sequence.**

---

```
j =0
       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

j = 1
       1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

j = 2
       1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

j = 3
       1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

j = 4
       1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

...so on
```